# Getting null when trying to access variables from another class, in Java

Tags: java, android, null

I have two classes and I want to pass a (geo-point) variable on touch from one to the other, so that I can calculate the distance between user current location and the geo-point.

Long story short:

My first class is named Session and the second Calculation - they are in the same package.

I declare the variables as public in the main class. On touch, I save the users current location into the (public) geo-point variable called *userposition*.

Then in the second class I use

```
Session pass = new Session();
```

to create an instance of the Session. After which I try to retrieve the *userposition* variable:

```
Geopoint position = pass.userposition;
```

But it keeps returning null and throws exception even if I tested the variable on the main class and works great ... What am I missing here??

The main code for Session is:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.maps);
    // Blah blah blah

    // And here i declare the GestureDetector...I working with google maps.
    Gest = new GestureDetector(new SimpleOnGestureListener());

    mapView.getOverlays().add(new Overlay() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e, MapView mapView) {
            Gest.onTouchEvent(e);
            return super.onTouchEvent(e, mapView);
        }
    });

    Gest.setOnDoubleTapListener(new OnDoubleTapListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
            // and in here i set the variable which works fine i tested it
            // in a textView
            userposition = myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation();
        }
    });
}
```

And for my Calculation class:

```
public Overlays(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
    super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
    mContext = context;
}

public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
    mOverlays.add(overlay);
    populate();
}

@Override
protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mOverlays.get(i);
}

@Override
public int size() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mOverlays.size();
}

@Override
public boolean onTap(int index) {
    // and here i try to get the variable by taping a marker on map (its a
    // lot of code no need to post works fine too)

    Session pass = new Session();
    Geopoint position = pass.userposition;
}
```

And then I get the null pointer exception.

What I noticed (I'm not so good at Java so I will try to explain) is that I can pass a variable like an integer (I tried it) from the main class Session. The thing is that to pass the geo-point, I need to pass the variable into the Gesture Detection onDoubleTap method inside the Session ... something like pass.onDoubleTap.userposition because that is the variable I need, and in that class the variable is not null. But how I go about doing that??

Comment: Main method is static? so maybe the variable is static? can you post code?

Comment: is userposition a static variable? If it's an instance variable then try using getter/setter to set/get the value. Also, could you please post your code?

Comment: That doesn't seem to work....somehow the variable is hidden in the statement and its real value is hidden to other classes...

Comment: i mean in the gesture detector double tap listener

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved it by declaring the variable `static`, so that it can be shared across all classes in the package.